# Does TextField onChange method trigger the build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have this:

```
class SomethingState extends State<Something> {
    String name;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextField(
            onChange: (text) {
                name = text
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Do I have to wrap `name = text` in `setState` to trigger the build method or no because when the user types something in the TextField it already does that?

This is how I have it now and it works, but I want to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: TextField is already itself a StatefulWidget, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value will change without `setState` but will not change on the UI. To update the UI you must use `setState` and rebuild the widgets.

*This code for the question in the comments*

```
class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
   final controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: TextField(controller: controller,),),
        FlatButton(child: Text("change"),onPressed: (){
          controller.text = 'new text';
        },)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: UI as in the text within to `TextFeild`? That does change

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. but if you want to change the TextFeild's text you don't need `setState`. You can do it like this `textEditingController.text = 'new text';`